# I cannot to authentication to root in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, bash, tkinter

I have a small program to just update the linux system. I would like when the program starts ask me to enter root password, in GUI menu "Authentication is required to run your program". I tried to put gksudo instead sudo. When I run the program there is below error!

**Please can anyone help how to fix it??**

```
Script not started as root. Running sudo..
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Python/upgrade_test.py", line 17, in <module>
    root = Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2023, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
Running. Your euid is 0
```

CODE:

```
from tkinter import *
import subprocess
import os
import sys


euid = os.geteuid()
if euid != 0:
    print ("Script not started as root. Running sudo..")
    args = ['pkexec', sys.executable] + sys.argv + [os.environ]
    # the next line replaces the currently-running process with the sudo
    os.execlpe('pkexec', *args)

print ('Running. Your euid is', euid)


root = Tk()
root.title('Update system')
#root.geometry("290x100")

def button_add1():
    os.system("apt-get update")
    os.system("apt-get upgrade")


def button_add4():
    root.destroy()

button_1 = Button(root, text="Upgrade system",  padx=40, pady=20, command=button_add1)
button_4 = Button(root, text="Quit", padx=40, pady=20, command=button_add4)

button_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
button_4.grid(row=0, column=4)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you run the script without the `pkexec` stuff, i.e. remove lines before `root = Tk()` except the import statements?

Comment: Yes, It works perfect, without pkexec stuff.

Comment: @acw1668 Do you have anydesk? Would you like to share my program to check it?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line:

```
os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0'
```

Comment: I put this line but not work! There is the same message

Answer (score 0):

From `man pkexec` :

```
The environment that PROGRAM will run it, will be set to a minimal known and safe
environment in order to avoid injecting code through LD_LIBRARY_PATH or similar
mechanisms. In addition the PKEXEC_UID environment variable is set to the user id of the 
process invoking pkexec. As a result, pkexec will not allow you to run X11 applications as
another user since the $DISPLAY and $XAUTHORITY environment variables are not set. These
two variables will be retained if the org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.allow_gui annotation
on an action is set to a nonempty value; this is discouraged, though, and should only be
used for legacy programs.
```

So you need to set `org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.allow_gui annotation` annotation

Comment: It doesn't work. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203136/how-do-i-run-gui-applications-as-root-by-using-pkexec/203149#203149

Comment: If I run pkexec bleachbit, the program ask me the password then run the program. pkexec in my linux machine works fine!